# Calculating 2D line-line intersection

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I calculate the point at which a line crosses y = -1 when the line is defined by a single point and an angle (presumably with 0 degrees/rads being vertical)?

Comment: you would write the equation of the line in terms of `x,y`, and would look for a solution with `y=-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fumbling around on Wolfram Alpha and some trial and error I think the answer to my question is `m = tan(theta+90); intersect = -(y - x * m + 1) / m`